# cannot view the entire text in Case comment

Tags: case, related-list, case-comment

I am trying to include the case comments related list on one of the case page layout. I can view the entire comment in classic interface but on lightning if it click view All in the Case comment related list it just shows very less content  on the comment column and there are no actions associated with it to see entire comment.

[image]

Can anyone suggest how I can view the entire comment content here in lightning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the down-arrow in the "Comment" header, and it should show you an option to either "clip text" (the default, which you're currently seeing that truncates the text) or "wrap text".

Selecting "wrap text" will show you the entirety of the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually Wrap the text by clicking on the arrow near the Comment Header and selecting Wrap Text, but I dont believe there is a way to set the default behaviour to wrap the text.

[image]
It looks like this functionality has been requested in this [Salesforce Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CPj5QAG) and people have [posted about it](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019Ya5QAE)
and it seems there is no point and click solution to solve for now. From my experience, upvoted Ideas can get delivered anywhere from the next Salesforce release to the next millenium (usually the case.

Salesforce is a love hate relationship. One way to solve this could be to create a custom lightning component or LWC to ensure text is wrapped.

Here is an [example for a dataTable](https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2020/03/24/how-to-set-wrap-text-as-default-for-columns-in-lightningdatatable-spring20delight/)
using either the Attribute ['wrap-text-max-lines'](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification) and or using the wrapText property of the column attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jkmKQAQ&title=case-comments-do-not-show-the-full-text-in-the-related-list) with salesforce and As a workaround, you can view the Case Comments in the Feed view.

Thanks